# How to print out a dictionary without a new dictionary variable?

Tags: python

How to create and append dictionary at the same time?

```
def buildList(theDict):
    array=[]
    for a,b in theDict.iteritems():
        array.append([a,b])

    return array
print buildList({"a": 1,"b": 2,"c": 3})
```

This prints out a list of lists. I want to print out a list of dictionaries without creating any new variables.

Comment: You want a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary has one single key/value pair?  In other words you want your example to build `[{"a":1}, {"b":2}, {"c":3}]`  Is this correct?

Comment: Thats actually the right way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to do something like that?

Comment: yes. i want a list of dictionarie

Comment: im practicing my python conversion skills, why is it that hard to do it?

Comment: its homework, i tried many ways. but im supposed to append a a dictionary made out of a and b without creating a new dictionary value.

Comment: `array.append({a:b})` instead of `array.append([a,b])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, this code should work.

```
def list_of_dicts(d):
    return [{key:value} for key, value in d.iteritems()]

print list_of_dicts({"a": 1,"b": 2,"c": 3})
```

`list_of_dicts()` uses a list comprehension, which creates a new `dict` with a single entry for each key/value pair in the passed-in dictionary.

Do you see how you could use a list comprehension to re-write your example, and return a list of lists?  It would just require changing three characters in the above.

P.S. I used PEP 8 names (lower_case rather than camelCase).

Comment: The list comprehension is the best way.  You could do it by making a variable with an empty list, and have a for loop append to the empty list, like your example.  You could use a generator expression and use `list()` to explicitly force it to expand out to a list, but that's sort of silly.  Maybe you could do something recursive where a function returns sublists...  Really, the list comprehension is the best way to do it.

Comment: If you just want to *print* the values, you could do that with a `for` loop that calls `print`, or you could build up a string.  But really the list comprehension is the best way!

Comment: yes but i don't understand list comprehension well, so im not really allowed to use it.

Comment: You aren't supposed to create any new variables, *and* you aren't supposed to use the easiest way to create a list without variables?  Every other way to build the list seems harder.  Maybe you are supposed to use one variable, the list, and append values to that?

Comment: thats what i'm doing.. did u see my example? now i just need to append a dictionary without using a new dictionary variable

Answer (score 1):

`array.append({a:b})` instead of `array.append([a,b])`

or use [List Comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)

```
array = [{a:b} for a,b in theDict.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer already is almost what you need.  When you append to the list, you are creating a new list, using this bit of code: `[a, b]`

So, replace that bit of code with a different bit of code, one that creates a dictionary.  You know how to create a dictionary!

If you need a hint, take a look at the list comprehension in my other answer, and see if you can figure out how the list comprehension creates new dictionary values.

I know you can figure this out!